# Allan Variance Plot

Tags: excel, function, data-analysis

Can anybody explain the sigma part of the equation attached for Allan Variance? How Can I calculate this equation in excel?[Allan Variance Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUApE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the reply from 落雪绽菊.
Different methods will have different formulas for short-term stability measurement, so you have to write several formulas, none of which is universal; the short-term stability measurement usually has a sampling time from 0.001 to 10s. Fortunately, it can be recorded manually, but it cannot be recorded below 1s. To realize manual recording, automatic measurement is generally adopted. Usually, the calculation is completed after this process, and it is of little significance to enter the calculation in execl. Here is the simplest one. If a1:a101 is the data area, enter `=SQRT(SUM((A2:A101-A1:A100)^2)/(2*100))`
in a certain cell in an array mode.

This is for your reference only. English is not my native language.The text is Google Translated, please excuse typing errors.